# expo Image-Picker No video option on launchCameraAsync({mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All}) on Android devices

Tags: react-native, expo

There is an issue in expo image-picker when I launch the device camera with:

```js
launchCameraAsync({mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All})
```

It doesn't give me the video record option just the still image option on Android devices, but it does so on iOS devices.

What I want is a way to allow the user to take photos and videos from the camera preview on both iOS and Android.

[Camera preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwsVL.jpg)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: check expo-camera which provides the api to record videos.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: Same issue here, did you find any solution ? 
Would like to add that ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos works fine but can't manage to get both working together

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a reported issue in the expo repo for expo-image-picker:

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/18759

In this issue I explain that it looks like this functionality is not possible in the native Android platform. I am not a android developer so I could be wrong but it looks as though you can only launch capture intents for either photo or video, there is no intent for photo and video that I could see.

In this issue the suggested workaround by another Developer is what I ended up using:

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

const pickerOptions: ImagePicker.ImagePickerOptions = {
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
    allowsEditing: false,
    allowsMultipleSelection: false,
  };

const openCameraAsync = async () => {
    const status = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();

    if (!status.granted) {
      return;
    }

    if (Platform.OS === 'android' && pickerOptions.mediaTypes === ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All) {
      //On android, we can't select both images and videos in the camera.
      androidSelectVideoOrImagePrompt();
      //We don't need to continue here, because the prompt will call the openCameraAsync function again.
      return;
    }


    const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync(pickerOptions);

    await mediaResponseAsync(result);
}

const androidSelectVideoOrImagePrompt = () => {
    Alert.alert('Select Media', 'Would you like to take a picture or record a video?', [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        style: 'cancel',
      },
      {
        text: 'Image',
        onPress: () => {
          pickerOptions.mediaTypes = ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images;
          openCameraAsync();
        },
      },
      {
        text: 'Video',
        onPress: () => {
          pickerOptions.mediaTypes = ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos;
          openCameraAsync();
        },
      },
    ]);
  };
```

Really the documentation should be updated for this feature if I am correct but here is a solution and explanation for anyone else that has this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this

```
 await ImagePicker({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,
        allowsEditing: true,
        quality: 1,
        aspect: [16, 9],
      });
```

[reference issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/6224)

Comment: Thank you, But what I looking for is to allow to user to use both the camera and video record.

Comment: @MajdMousa in this case use `ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All`
and check in another devices